# PyTorch lightening resume training from last epoch and weights

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, pytorch

I am using *PyTorch Lightening* `trainer` for pre-training a large model. I know I can resume training from old weights but that does not contain old hyper-parameters (lr, last_epoch, etc.). Is there any automatic way to resume training? OR Do I need to overload `Checkpoint Callback` or `CSVLogger` to search for old cvs logs and get last `epoch` number?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of load from checkpoint, use `resume_from_checkpoint` in trainer.

```
# resume from a specific checkpoint
trainer = Trainer(resume_from_checkpoint="some/path/to/my_checkpoint.ckpt")
```

See more details here https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common/trainer.html#resume-from-checkpoint .

Comment: Here, it requires to provide exact name of model, whereas during training is save model with version number. That means I have to manually get the name of last model and provide that path?

Comment: You can access best model path or last model path through checkpoint callback attributes, e.g., `self.trainer.checkpoint_callback.best_model_path` or `self.trainer.checkpoint_callback.last_model_path`.

Comment: https://github.com/Lightning-AI/lightning/blob/61c28cb428a13c2aea6d7f3f55e0f00431a4ea4e/src/pytorch_lightning/callbacks/model_checkpoint.py#L238

Answer (score 1):

`Trainer(resume_from_checkpoint="some/path/to/my_checkpoint.ckpt")` has been depreciated. New method is: `self.trainer.fit(self.model, self.data_module, ckpt_path = self.ckpt_path)`. It requires to save *best/last* model after certain number of epochs with pre-defined *path+name* and then retrieve from path for resuming the training.

I am wondering if this method would be effective for transfer learning i.e. changing only few `fc` layer for some other task.